# Proving first countability of $\mathbb{R}$ under the particular point topology.

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is a first countable space with respect to the particular point topology defined by:

$$\mathcal{T} = \{I\subseteq \mathbb{R} : I = \emptyset \text{ or } p\in I\}$$

for an arbitrary point $p\in \mathbb{R}$. My approach was to find a countable neighbourhood basis of a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ other than $p$. I believe that the subset consisting of the closed interval $\mathcal{B}_x := \{[x,p]\}$ does the job, as any neighbourhood of $x$ must contain the closed interval (assuming that $x<p$, otherwise we just take the closed interval $[p,x]$ as the basis element instead) $[x,p]$, and the closed interval is considered open under the particular point topology. Clearly $\mathcal{B}_x$ is countable as its cardinality is $1$, and so it is a countable neighbourhood basis, which implies first countability.

Question: Is my proof valid? I was checking my proof with chatgpt but it keeps telling me that I should have a collection rather than a single set, and it also said that the set I provided is not open, which is clearly false by the definition of the topology above.

Comment: You are stronlgy advised against using ChatGPT for anything in Mathematics.  Just not reliable.

Comment: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000009/properties/P000028

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In this topology $\{x,p\}$ is an open set containing $x$. Instead of $\mathcal B_x=[x,p]$ or $\mathcal B_x=[p,x]$ you have to take $\mathcal B_x=\{\{x,p\}\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes a lot of sense, I appreciate it.

Comment: I think you want $\mathcal B_x=\{\{x,p\}\}$, right?

Comment: @MW Yes, sure. Thanks.